# how to get access token after windows azure active directory authentication

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

we have successfully implemented the active directory authentication using the process given at the url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx . Here we are able to authenticate the user on the https://login.microsoftonline.com/ and return back to web site but we are not able to get access token after successful authentication. following code through which we are able to access the user name, surname etc after successful authentication but not the access token.
can you provide me the code through which we can get the access token after authentication.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
            string fullname =
                   string.Format("{0} {1}", cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value,
                   cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value);
            ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Dear {0}, welcome to the Expense Note App",
                              fullname);                              

            return View();

        }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the token? The WIF infra takes care of validating the token and creating claims out of it.

Comment: we need this token for calling the api. and this token will be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to access the security token that was used:

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
ClaimsIdentity ci = cp.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
BootstrapContext bc = ci.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
SecurityToken securityToken = bc.SecurityToken;
```

You also need to set the **saveBootstrapContext** attribute in your config file:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
    ...
</system.identityModel>
```