# Get Azure Active Directory Token with username and password

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to authenticate my client using AAD and automate this using a Windows Service. In AAD .NET SDK, There's two methods, `AcquireTokenAsync` and `AcquireToken`, but i can't use either of these methods, the await call will stay forever with no response, and when i do something like this:

```
result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceHostUri, clientId, new UserCredential(hardcodedUsername, hardcodedPassword)).Result;
```

The object returns a status of `Waiting for Activation` & `Code 31`..

Now, Is there anyway to acquire the token using hardcoded username and password?

My full code:

```
        string hardcodedUsername = "username";
        string hardcodedPassword = "password";

        string tenant = "tenantId@onmicrosoft.com";
        string clientId = "clientId";
        string resourceHostUri = "https://management.azure.com/";
        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";

        string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);


        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
            try
            {

                result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceHostUri, clientId, new UserCredential(hardcodedUsername, hardcodedPassword)).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return result;
```

*I'm trying to get access to Azure API.*

**UPDATE 1:**

I got this in the output when i tried to `await` the call, i think this might help:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory TokenCache: Looking up cache for a token... 
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory d__0: Sending user realm discovery request to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/UserRealm/*username*?api-version=1.0'
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory d__4: User with hash '***' detected as 'Federated'

Comment: Have you tried to made the method `async` and put `await` in front of `authContext.AcquireTokenAsync()` method call?

Comment: Yes, and it takes forever with no response, i mentioned that in my question

Comment: Can you share the complete code (including method signature and how you're calling this method)?

Comment: The is shared above, This is just a test method  `public AuthenticationResult getAccessToken()
        {  }`

Comment: What adal version are you using?

Comment: It's '2.18.206251556'

Answer (score 1):

try below link code

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/partnercenter/dn974935.aspx

[how to get access token after windows azure active directory authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437173/how-to-get-access-token-after-windows-azure-active-directory-authentication)

[How to get current token from Azure ActiveDirectory application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962472/how-to-get-current-token-from-azure-activedirectory-application)

```
// Get OAuth token using client credentials 
string tenantName = "GraphDir1.OnMicrosoft.com";
string authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantName;

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

// Config for OAuth client credentials  
string clientId = "118473c2-7619-46e3-a8e4-6da8d5f56e12";
string key = "hOrJ0r0TZ4GQ3obp+vk3FZ7JBVP+TX353kNo6QwNq7Q=";
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, key);
string resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
string token;
try
{
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCred);
    token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
catch (AuthenticationException ex)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("Acquiring a token failed with the following error: {0}", ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        //  You should implement retry and back-off logic according to
        //  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168916.aspx . This topic also
                                //  explains the HTTP error status code in the InnerException message. 
        Console.WriteLine("Error detail: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 things: 1) OP wants to fetch the credentials using username/password combination and not by using client credentials and 2) OP is using async methods. What you've shown is sync method and you're using client credentials.

Comment: Exactly, as my app in AAD is a Native Client, i can't get a key to do this kind of auth, what i need is to use my credentials (Username and Password)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<AuthenticationResult> t = getAccessToken();
        t.Wait();
        var result = t.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
        Console.WriteLine("Please any key to terminate the program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> getAccessToken()
    {
        string hardcodedUsername = "username";
        string hardcodedPassword = "password";

        string tenant = "tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
        string clientId = "clientId";
        string resourceHostUri = "https://management.azure.com/";
        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";

        string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);


        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceHostUri, clientId, new UserCredential(hardcodedUsername, hardcodedPassword));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

What I have done is made `getAccessToken()` method `async` and inside that the code is made to  wait to get the token when you call `authContext.AcquireTokenAsync`.

Comment: I tried that before, waiting with no any response, but this time i checked the output, there's something interesting.. i edited my question so you can see the output..

Comment: It looks like the user is from other Azure AD. Can you try by using credentials of a user in the AD where you created the application?

Comment: Yes, the user is in the directory with full permissions!

Comment: Yes I got this code working with a TOKEN response!  So delete the AWAIT in this code: result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceHostUri, clientId, new UserCredential(hardcodedUsername, hardcodedPassword));                                       then delete t.wait() from the calling code, and walla!

Comment: also not that UserCredential only access the username for now for security purposes.